# What does the light on the power switch of my Nintendo Wii indicate with its colors?

Tags: nintendo-wii

Sometimes the light is Green. This clearly means the Wii is on.
Sometimes the light is Red. I assume this means its off.
Sometiems when the Wii appears to be off, the light is orange. I'm not at all sure what this means.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The red and orange lights indicate whether the Wii is connected to the Nintendo Network or not. If the light is red, it means your Wii isn't connected and won't get mail, updates, etc. until you start it again, while the orange light means it is connected.